# RegEx to extract a string using two possible delimiters

Tags: regex, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

I want to extract a timespan from a AppInsights log entry using Kusto RegEx.
The timespan can have two possible forms:

```
TotalDuration [1 day, 2:09:13.830470] Categories
TotalDuration [2:09:13.830470] Categories
```

I have worked out how to extract the whole timespan:
RegEx: `"TotalDuration \\[(.*?)\\] Categories"`

But I want to extract the timespan component (2:09:13.830470) only.

Is there a way that I can say I want the value bounded by:
( day, )(timespan here)(] Categories)
or the value bounded by:
(TotalDuration [)(timespan here)(] Categories)

I.e. the first delimiter can be either of two different strings.
Something like this:
( day, ***OR*** TotalDuration [)(timespan here)(] Categories)

Comment: You *may* be able to match with the following regex. If there is a match the timespan will be held in capture group 1: `^TotalDuration +\[(?:\d+ +day, +)?([^]]+)`. I say "may" because I don't know the capabilities of your regex engine. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/GOgC2c/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this one:
`TotalDuration \\[(?:.+ )?(.*?)\\] Categories`
or this one:
`TotalDuration \\[(?:.+,)?(.*?)\\] Categories`
Example: https://regex101.com/r/O2WJ3q/1
Basically you can skip all characters in [] until some character like `,` or whitespace

Comment: `TotalDuration \[(?:.+ )?(.*?)\] Categories` did the job.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match until the last space between the square brackets and make it optional `(?:[^\[\]\n]+ )?`

Instead of using `.*?` you could make it a bit more efficient using a negated character class `([^\]\[\n]*)` as well for the capturing group.

```
\bTotalDuration \[(?:[^\[\]\n]+ )?([^\]\[\n]*)\] Categories\b
```

- `\bTotalDuration`  Word boundary and match `TotalDuration`
- `\[` Match `[`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^[]\n]+`  Match 1+ times any char other than a newline or square bracket
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\]\[\n]*` Match 0+ times any char other than a newline or square bracket
- `)` Close group 1
- `\] Categories\b` Match `] Categories` and word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CDBlWF/1)